# how to add another folder level to send framework autoloader?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, autoloader

i have this simple setup

```
-controllers
    IndexController.php
          here somewhere i call new Application_Model_Sites_Sites()
+layouts
-models
    -sites
        Sites.php
           class Application_Model_Sites_Sites
           { .. }
+library
+public
```

and i get `Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_Sites_Sites' not found in ..`

The strange thing is that under xampp in windows it works perfect, but when i place it on a linux server i get that error

I'm thinking i need to tell zend about those sub-folders, but i have the impression that it should know about them because i use them in the class name

Any ideas what am i missing?

```
application.ini
    [production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
    phpSettings.display_errors = 1
    includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
    bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
    bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
    appnamespace = "Application"
    resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
    resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
    resources.view[]=
    resources.view.helperPath.Zend_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
    [staging : production]
    [testing : production]
```

and by bootstrap is empty for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldnt it be `Models` with an `s` - `Application_Models_Sites_Sites`?

Comment: @Patrioticcow hmm...since this is working in xampp on windows and not in linux, I feel that this is a problem with upper/lower case. You should take a look in that direction.

Comment: i double checked. the folders are ok. for some reason it doesn't know about the models folder

Comment: you were right the `sites` folder from within `models` folder should be `Sites` :)